# While using reindex method of pandas on a data frame why the original values are lost?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

This is the original Dataframe`tols` :
[image]
**What I wanted :** I wanted to convert this above data-frame into this multi-indexed column data-frame :
[image]
I managed to do it by this piece of code :

```
# tols : original dataframe
cols =    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'] 
['P','Q']])
tols.set_axis(cols, axis = 1, inplace = False)
```

**What I tried :** I tried to do this with the `reindex` method like this :

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'], 
['P','Q']])
tols.reindex(cols, axis = 'columns')
```

it resulted in an output like this : 
[image]

**My problem :**
As you could see in the output above all my original numerical values go missing on employing the `reindex` method. In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) page it was clearly mentioned :
*Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, placing NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index. A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one.* So i don't understand:

- Where did i particularly err in employing the `reindex` method to lose my original values
- How should i have employed the `reindex` method correctly to get my desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign new columns names, only necessary same length of columns in original DataFrame with length of MultiIndex:

```
tols.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['Y','X'], ['P','Q']])
```

---

Problem with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) here is pandas is looking for values of cols in original columns names and because they're not found so they're set to missing values.

Comment: Wow that was super-short...any ideas why reindex didn't work out ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the intended behaviour, from the documentation:

> Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, **placing
>   NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1-
One way which i tried is create a list of elements that you want as index and append it as a new column to the dataframe.
Step 2 -
Use set_index() and assign that column to set_index..
Done, now you have index changed to elements of the list you made in step 1.

Thanks